# get a reference to the control from ng-click event

Tags: angularjs

I have a table row dynamically being populated with clickable images. When the image is clicked I need to pass its unique id to the controller. I have tried many different ways but so far unsuccessful. What I tried:

```
<td ng-repeat="Type in Types">
    <img ng-src="../../Images/{{Type.Path}}" ng-title="{{Type.TypeId}}" ng-model="n_type" ng-click="Process()" />
</td>

 $scope.Process = function () {
    console.log($scope.n_type);
    $scope.$parent.n_type = $scope.n_type;
 }
```

and

```
<td ng-repeat="Type in Types">
    <div data-ng-init="imgId='{{Type.TypeId}}';">
        <img ng-src="../../Images/{{Type.Path}}" data-ng-attr-id="imgId" ng-title="{{Type.TypeId}}" ng-model="n_type" ng-click="Process(imgId)" />
    </div>   
</td>

 $scope.Process = function () {
    console.log($scope.imgId);
    $scope.$parent.n_type = $scope.imgId;
 }
```

But in both cases the result is "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the ID as a param to your Process function:

```
<td ng-repeat="Type in Types">
    <img ng-src="../../Images/{{Type.Path}}" ng-click="Process(Type.imgId)" />  
</td>
```

and then

```
$scope.Process = function (imgId) {
    $scope.$parent.n_type = imgId;
 }
```

Comment: I'll add : don't use $parent. If you have a parent controller initialize n_type in your parent controller ($scope.n_type = null;) and just do in your child controller : $scope.n_type= imgId. You may not control the number of children scope that you have between the parent scope you're aiming and the child where you are.

Comment: As a best practice I totally agree, though it's not directly relevant to the question asked.

Comment: yes but sometimes people ask questions with some code like this because they're totally lost, so many people appreciate that we add some more information not directly relevant to the question but relevant to their code :)

Comment: I'm right there with ya, I was just trying to make sure @ElenaDBA understood that was a sidebar and not the main event